# Importing Numbers and data from a text file and adding them individually to an array and entering place in aray to acquire values

Tags: python, file, file-handling

Im pretty much a beginner when it comes to python, only able to do the easiest parts of it. I wanted to ask how i would add numbers from a text file and add them to an array. I dont have a set text file so I'll take any format in which the numbers are ordered in the file. Furthermore, i wanted to know how i could do something like this:

> In the .txt file:

```
1    T-shirt    5.00
2    Jeans    6.00
3...
```

then import it into the code and ask the user for a number. When they put the number in, it would display the string/text in the middle and then add the price to a different array/variable for adding... I'd also like a way in which i could add to the data above, adding new lines with different numbers to fetch the string and price next to it. The above text is just an example of course, since the file is only required to fetch the data and not to be read via notepad etc.

I dont really know if this is the kind of question i should be asking here but thanks for any replies regardless

Comment: Here is the documentation for reading and writing files in Python. Perhaps that can help you work out the next step. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you would need to read what stands in your file.
For that you should make yourself familiar with the `with` statement and how to handle files:
[How to handle files](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)

While you read your file line for line you can check every line if what you read is a string or number.
For that, it would be good when you would use a format like .csv where your "key" and "value" are separated for example with a ",".
You could then use the `split()` method in python to split your string.
Then you have 2 strings. The "number" string you would need to convert into a `float or int`.
Then you could append your variable to your array. `array.append(your_variable)`.

For the rest, you should do some research for yourself.
Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions and not for: "thats my project, please say how I can do that".

:)